# iOS 9.3 simulator get closed frequently with appium 1.5.3, why?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

iOS 9.3 simulator get closed frequently with Appium 1.5.3, why?

Every time ios simulator get closed and run the application after 4 or 5 times.

Also, it took long time to reboot every time

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same situation, and I just plain and simple deleted 1.5.3 and went back to reliable **1.4.13**

You can find the previous versions in: 
https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/

Comment: But in ios version drop down in appium It will not display 9.3 than?

Comment: Appium will activate iOS Simulator from Xcode. If you specified that you want iPhone6, iOS 9.2 then it will fire that one up. You would mainly need to install XCode Simulator that is 9.3 version, as far as I can see XCode does not have 9.3 simulator yet.

Comment: Latest XCode 7.3 now comes with iOS 9.3 simulator.